# Converting Curl to a Request in Python

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am trying to work out how to convert curl request to python, but I am not 100% sure what is what. How do you pull apart a curl request so it will work with a pyhton request (I would prefer not use any 3rd party packages)

```
curl -i -XPOST 'http://10.16.1.35:8086/write?db=maintenance' --data-binary 'temperature,pi=Raspberry,sensor=Blue value=64.50 1490643440916250112'
```

and

```
curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb' --data-binary @cpu_data.txt
```

I don't understand what elements in here are what so I can convert the request.

Thankyou!

Comment: Paste your command into https://curlconverter.com/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this in two ways.

1. Using pycurl library which acts like an interface to cURL library. You can take a look at the documentation [here](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/index.html)
2. You can send a http request with content type, header and parameters using the requests library for python. You can take a look at their documentation [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

I hope this helps.